# Argument passing in Jenkins Tool

Tags: jenkins, arguments, command-line-arguments, jenkins-plugins

I am new to Jenkins and I am exploring Jenkins tool So please let me know how to pass argument in Jenkins at the time of Click on Build option??

Comment: that means we write read command in script and at the time of run I pass argument through keyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins support parameterised builds. [Full documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) is pretty neat

The option to add parameter is shown when you check "the build is parameterised" checkbox. Also you may find "rebuild" plugin useful for re-running the job with params.

[image]